# Asking two closely related questions: to merge or not to merge?

Tags: discussion

I have a question here, about locking the elbow joint when using forward kinematics.

[How to lock elbow rotation (forward kinematics)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/how-to-lock-elbow-rotation-forward-kinematics)

So, I also want to ask the same question with inverse kinematics.
With minor edits and a modified screenshot (out of 3) the two questions would look very similar. But expect the answer would be quite different so I feel worried about conflating these two questions.

What should I do?